# Call exported function in binary file

Tags: c, linux, dlopen, dlsym

I have binary file in linux (not `so` file) that exported some function.

I want to call from my c code(in runtime) to 1 of exported function, I know that with `dlsym` I can call to function in `so` file ,for example

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
void* libHandle =dlopen("/usr/lib/myLib/libutil.so", RTLD_LAZY);
if (!libHandle) {
 exit(1);
 }

void (*circle)(int x, int y, int r);
circle = dlsym(libHandle, "drawCircle");
circle(10,10,7);
dlclose(libHandle);
```

1) Can I call to function in runtime only on `so` file?

2)How do I check if the binary that I want call 1 of exported function is so file?

3)How do I convert binary file to so?

Comment: I think that in order for one to be able to even _find_ a function, the binary must have relocation information. So, if your binary is a (stripped) executable, it probably doesn't contain any information about function names.

Comment: If this file isn't a shared object (use `file` utility to verify), then what do you mean it exports functions?

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond even file  isn't so . I can looking on export tab in Ida,and see some functions export